# Change the localhost setting

Tags: service

I followed the steps mentioned in this blog post..

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/dashboards-as-code-a-new-approach-to-visualizing-aws-apis/

and was able to start the service.

```
$ steampipe dashboard
[ Wait    ] Loading Workspace
[ Wait    ] Starting Dashboard Server
[ Message ] Workspace loaded
[ Message ] Initialization complete
[ Ready   ] Dashboard server started on 9194 and listening on local
[ Message ] Visit http://localhost:9194
[ Message ] Press Ctrl+C to exit
```

But I need to host it on some-company.com:9194 instead of localhost.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In directory `~/.steampipe/config` find `database` and edit listen to be network

```
options "database" {
  port   = 9193                     # any valid, open port number
  listen = "network"                  # local, network
  search_path = "aws,aws2,gcp,gcp2" # comma-separated string; an exact search_path
}
```

Comment: easier way  #steampipe dashboard --dashboard-listen network